# Replace a Normed space property

Tags: normed-spaces

How to show that we may replace the property of a norm $$||x||=0 \iff x=0$$ by $$||x||=0 \implies x = 0$$ without altering the concept
of a norm.

Comment: This implies the other direction though.

Answer (score 0):

$\|cx\|=|c|\|x\|$. Put $c=0$ to get $\|0\|=0$. Hence $\|x\|=0$ iff $x=0$.

Comment: @Mathematician It means we **can** replace  the condition '$\|x\|=0$ iff $x=0$' by the condition $\|x\|=0 \implies x=0$'.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand how

Comment: One part of the equivalence is given in the  new definition and I proved the converse part. So the new definition agrees with the old.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $||0|| \ne 0.$ For each scalar $ \alpha$ we get

$$||0||=|| \alpha \cdot 0||=|\alpha| \cdot ||0||.$$

Hence $|\alpha|=1$ for each scalar $ \alpha$, a contradiction.